# Show tooltips of multiple node by hovering on a node in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, treeview, mousemove, mousehover

Using D3 examples [(1)](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) and [(2)](http://bl.ocks.org/anotherjavadude/2952964), I created a collapsible tree view in D3 where each node of tree has some information in its tooltip.

Please see my work [here](https://bl.ocks.org/sushilverma208016/7c0270671203def38eb9c329136bc2a2). In the tree, `node1` and `node2` are collapsible/expandable. Expanding `node2` will create `node4` and `node5`.

Each node is showing its tooltip on hovering (using `mouseover,mousemove,mouseout` events). Every node knows its parent and its children.

Now, my requirement is: when a node X is hovered, tooltips of all nodes in path from root to X, should be visible simultaneously.

For example: when I should hover `node4`, tooltips of three nodes: `node1`, `node2` and `node4` should be visible.

How can I achieve it in my example?

Answer (score 4):

I handled this problem by creating a div having tooltip when a node is hovered.

and called its parent recursively.

```
function mouseover(d) {
    var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .style("left", (d.y+120) + "px")
        .style("top", (d.x-20) + "px")
        .html(
            "<table style='font-size: 10px; font-family: sans-serif;' >"+
            "<tr><td>Name: </td><td>"+d.name+"</td></tr>"+
            "<tr><td>Value: </td><td>"+d.value+"</td></tr>"+
            "</table>"
        );
    if (d.parent) mouseover(d.parent);
}
```

In the mouseout event, I called all divs with tooptip class and removed them.

```
function mouseout(d) {
    d3.select("body").selectAll('div.tooltip').remove();
}
```

Find the revised implementation here: https://bl.ocks.org/sushilverma208016/0e7d251e1651f7193b965c33edd0ca36